# How do I align two rows of characters inside a tikzpicture node, when the second line contains mainly whitespace?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, alignment, text, white-space

I'm using tikzpicture to draw diagrams/flowcharts in my dissertation and I have encountered an alignment problem inside a node. The node contains two rows, the top row is the variable names and the second row is the variable values.

What I would like inside the node:

```
 Industry, Min employers, Max employers, Min employees, Max employees
        Y,             1,             5,            21,            29
```

As you can see, my desired output is that the bottom row has the values right-aligned with the variable names.

What I have is:
[image: Incorrectly formatted second row, text is centred with no spaces between the values].

I tried to increase the white space by adding spaces using the spacebar, and tikzpicture is ignoring those. How do I change my node so that the text lays out the way I want it?

Tikzpicture code is:

```
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style= {draw, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize, align=center}, 
    arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
    \node(Ind) {Industry data};
    \node[below = 1 cm of Ind] (IY) {Industry, Min employers, Max employers, Min employees, Max employees \\
        $Y$,                                        1,                                    5,                                 21,                                    29}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My caption.}
\label{flow:EmprEg}
\end{figure}
```

You can see where I have hit the spacebar multiple times in my effort to create the whitespaces. I had a look in the manual, and searching inside the PDF the term "whitespace" occurs once and is unrelated to my problem.

I searched on this site, and with my search terms I only located questions relating to alignment between nodes, and not alignment inside nodes.

How do I get my desired text alignment, with whitespace, inside a node?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding spaces is useless, as TeX treats consecutive spaces as a single one (except with `\obeyspaces`).

Anyway, why not simply use a tabular ?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style= {draw, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize, align=center},
    arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
    \node(Ind) {Industry data};
    \draw[->] (Ind) -- ++(0, -1cm) coordinate (IY);
    \node[below, align=center] at (IY) {%
      \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
        Industry & Min employers & Max employers & Min employees & Max employees \\
        $Y$      & 1             & 5             & 21            & 29
      \end{tabular}
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My caption.}
\label{flow:EmprEg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some way to give a south coordinate to the node containing the industry data? If I use IY.south for drawing arrows, it draws them from the top (which is where the IY is positioned) rather than the bottom.

Comment: @Michelle `IY` is a coordinate, not a node, so no, this isn't possible. `Ind` is a node, and you can also add a label to the node holding the tabular.

Comment: I put a non-draw node offset to create fix the problem.